# How can we use Edge IE Mode in Selenium Grid(RemoteWebDriver)?

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge, selenium-grid

MS will stop supporting IE from June 2022, we are trying to find out a workaround to use Edge IE mode to do health checks we have for our IE supported applications. However, I can't see any supporting documents which show how to use Edge IE mode in Selenium Grid.

Comment: Hi, may I know if you have got any chance to check [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549951/how-can-we-use-edge-ie-mode-in-selenium-gridremotewebdriver/71555846#71555846)? I am glad to help if you have any other questions. Please let me know about your test result.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the steps below to use Edge IE mode in Selenium Grid:

1. Download **selenium-server-4.1.2.jar** and **IE Driver Server** from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
2. Download the corresponding version of **Edge WebDriver** from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) (the same version as your Edge browser).
3. Put the paths of IE Driver Server and Edge WebDriver in **Environment PATH**.
4. Using the command prompt, navigate to the path of selenium server, then type on the command prompt to **launch a hub**:

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-4.1.2.jar hub
   ```
5. Using the command prompt, navigate to the same path and type on the command prompt to launch a node:

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-4.1.2.jar node
   ```
6. By default, the server will be listening on `http://localhost:4444`, and that’s the URL you should point your `RemoteWebDriver` tests.
7. Use the C# code below to run the automation test. The site will be opened in IE mode:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using OpenQA.Selenium;
   using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
   using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
   using System.Threading;

   namespace WebDriverTest
   {
       class seleniumgrid
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               var dir = @"E:\webdriver_path";
               var driver = "IEDriverServer.exe";
               if (!Directory.Exists(dir) || !File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, driver)))
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Failed to find {0} in {1} folder.", dir, driver);
                   return;
               }

               var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions { };
               ieOptions.AttachToEdgeChrome = true;
               ieOptions.EdgeExecutablePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";

               WebDriver webdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444"), ieOptions);
               webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
               Thread.Sleep(3000);
               webdriver.Close();
               webdriver.Quit();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note: Please change the paths and URLs to your owns.

Reference link: [Getting started with Selenium Grid](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/getting_started/)

Comment: where do we use the IEDriverServer? The code is checking if it's there, but doesn't do anything else. Can you tell me how you started the selenium server on the localhost? The command line can help.

Comment: We have put IEDriverServer in PATH, so we don't need to specify IEDriverServer path in code. The code will find the driver automatically.